# Android - Removed multiple objects within an ArrayList, but the adapter wont update correctly

Tags: java, android

I have an ArrayList of an object that serves as one row for a listview. I have a method so that on a long click the checked off items within the listview will be removed and updated accordingly. However, when the app runs all that happens are that those items who are checked now become unchecked--the item isnt removed at all.

Heres my code for that onClick. The row objects are checklistItems.

```
button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<Checklist> temp = new ArrayList<Checklist>();
            for (int i = checklistItems.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
                if (checklistItems.get(i).getValue() != 1)
                    temp.add(checklistItems.get(i));
            }

            checklistItems = temp;
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

I am sure my procedure for filtering out the unwanted items is fine...unless it isn't haha. I just don't understand why its behaving this way. Any help is appreciated!

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Checklist> {
ArrayList<Checklist> checklistItems;
Context context;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Checklist> resource){
    super(context, R.layout.list_view_row_item, resource);
    this.context = context;
    this.checklistItems = resource;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_row_item, parent, false);
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

    name.setText(checklistItems.get(position).getName());
    if (checklistItems.get(position).getValue() == 1)
        cb.setChecked(true);
    else
        cb.setChecked(false);
    return convertView;
}
```

}

EDIT: The onCreate method where the adapter is initialized:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ListView lv;
ArrayList<Checklist> checklistItems;
CustomAdapter myAdapter;
Button button;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

//        readItems();

```
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addItem);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            shortclick();
        }
    });

    button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<Checklist> temp = new ArrayList<Checklist>();
            for (int i = checklistItems.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
                if (checklistItems.get(i).getValue() == 1) // changed to == 1
                    temp.add(checklistItems.get(i));
            }

            //checklistItems = temp; //Don't change reference of Adapter data source

            checklistItems.clear(); //added
            checklistItems.addAll(temp); //added

            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return true;
        }
    });


    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    checklistItems = new ArrayList<Checklist>();
    checklistItems.add(new Checklist(0,"When you add a new item it will show here"));
    checklistItems.add(new Checklist(0,"Check the items that you've finished"));

    myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,checklistItems);
    lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);


}
```

The shortClick method :

```
    public void shortclick()
{
    EditText taskET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.taskET);
    String itemText = taskET.getText().toString();
    Checklist newTask = new Checklist(0,itemText);
    myAdapter.add(newTask);
    taskET.setText("");

}
```

The Checklist class:

```
public class Checklist {
int value;
String text;
boolean isChecked;

public Checklist(int value, String text){
    this.value = value;
    this.text = text;
}

public String getName(){
    return this.text;
}

public int getValue(){
    return this.value;
}

public void setValue(boolean isChecked){
    if (value == 1)
       isChecked = true;
    else
        isChecked = false;
}
```

}

Comment: What is `myAdapter`?

Comment: Each time you make modifications to your arrayList, you have to rebuild the adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the reference of the data source of an Adapter once it's been set as the data source.

The easiest way to get your desired result would be to call `clear()` on the data source, and then call `addAll()` to add the new data to the original data source.

```
button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        ArrayList<Checklist> temp = new ArrayList<Checklist>();
        for (int i = 0; i < checklistItems.size(); i++){
            if (checklistItems.get(i).getValue() == 0)
                temp.add(checklistItems.get(i));
        }

        //checklistItems = temp; //Don't change reference of Adapter data source

        checklistItems.clear(); //added
        checklistItems.addAll(temp); //added

        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return true;
    }
});
```

Edit, you also need to update the data with a listener for the checkbox, something like this:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_row_item, parent, false);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                checklistItems.get(position).setValue(isChecked);
            }
        });

        name.setText(checklistItems.get(position).getName());
        if (checklistItems.get(position).getValue() == 1)
            cb.setChecked(true);
        else
            cb.setChecked(false);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Actually that still did not solve my problem. Any ideas on what it could be? Im using the snippet you added with the only difference being that i am now iterating from i = 0 up to i < checklistItems.size()

Comment: Alright, I added the full onCreate method to my original post. Now what is happening is that the entire list disappears rather than the specific item(s) that is checked.

Comment: @yaman That would indicate that the items in your list are not getting updated correctly when they are checked.  Can you show your `shortclick();` method?

Comment: @yaman, I just realized that my last edit was incorrect, as you want to delete the checked items.  I'll update the answer again.

Comment: @yaman, it looks like your data is not getting updated when you check each item.  Do you have a listener on the checkbox set up in your Adapter to update the value in the ArrayList?

Comment: I do not! Ohhh that would explain why it!

Comment: Is setValue a new method of my Checklist class, not to be getValue? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I added your changes to my adapter however the checklist is now just reversing order. Meaning, the last item is now the first and so on. The longclick now just keeps reversing them

Comment: @yaman Ahh, that's because of the order of adding to the temp array!  Just reverse the order to go bottom up, I'll update the answer!

Comment: Haha! it still isn't fixing my problem. Its behaving exactly the same as it was before--unchecking all the options that were checked before. I've tried various iterating techniques including the one you last suggested and it always ends up behaving the same way. However, I did add the boolean check to the custom adapter but im not sure if its having any effect. Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: @yaman you have your variables reversed in the setValue() method!  It should be `if (isChecked) value = 1; else value = 0;`

Comment: haha you are so right! It works perfectly now! Thank you for the lesson on adapters and listeners! I learned a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, my guess is (I've had this partially happen to me before)
This is the line giving you an error:

```
checklistItems = temp;
```

When you assign that new value, it somehow messes with the Adapter.

I had my error happen when I set it to a new ArrayList

```
checkListItems = new ArrayList<?>();
```

You're probably better off removing the items from the original array as you're iterating. This'll save time and memory (you won't need to use temp)

```
    for (int i = checklistItems.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if (checklistItems.get(i).getValue() == 1)
            checklistItems.remove(i);
    }
```

Comment: I've tried that method before and tried it again. However, it still only unchecks the items that were checked and doesn't remove them

Answer (score 0):

Call `remove(`) on the ArrayList rather than `clear()`. Just be sure to also call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Also use `onItemLongClick()` rather than `onLongClick` so we can receive the position in the list.

```
button.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        checklistItems.remove(position);
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return true;
    }
});
```